# Pythonic way to set __init__ threeways argument:

Tags: python, input, init

Hi I have a fairly simple question related to some input formatting. I've implemented a Satellite class that may receive as an **optional** argument, instruments, one or many of them.  I need this to be represented internally as a list.

```
class Satellite(object):

    def __init__(self,other_arguments,instruments = None):
        

        self._other_arguments = other_arguments

        if not instruments:
            self.instruments = []
        elif not isinstance(instrumentss,list):
            self.instruments = [instruments]
        else:
            self.instruments = instruments
    
    @property
    def instruments(self):
        return self._instruments

    @instruments.setter
    def instruments(self,instrument):
        for instr in instruments:
            if not isinstance(instr, Instrument):
                raise Exception("error message")
        self._instruments = instruments
```

If the users wants just to input one instrument, I don't feel that is nice to make them pass as an argument the 1 item list `[the_one_instrument]` instead of `the_one_instrument`

What I've implemented works, but I feel it is too verbose, maybe there is another way of attacking this issue.

Comment: "If the users wants just to input one instrument, I don't feel that is nice to make them pass as an argument the 1 item list [the_one_instrument] instead of the_one_instrument" generally, it is not nice for arguments to take inconsistent types. Much less nice than having to create a list when you only need one item

Comment: Anyway, what you've written to accomplish this is perfectly pythonic.

Comment: Surely the Pythonic way of doing this would be to write `def __init__(self, other_arguments, *instruments):`?  Although I agree it's better to just take a list consistently (I dislike *args and **kwargs because they're hard to typecheck).

Comment: Thx for both comments. I will try to apply this feedback into the code.